# NoReverseMatch at django

Tags: python, django

Either I'm getting a weird URL error in my project or I'm missing something.

I want to get the profile ID and show the informations in a template called "profile.html". Quite simple isn't it?

But I'm getting a NoReverseMatch error every time I call this "profile url".

My `urls.py`:

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib import admin
from sugar import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^area51/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^search/', views.search, name="search"),
    url(r'^terms/', views.terms, name="terms"),
    url(r'^thanks/', views.thanks, name="thanks"),
    url(r'^create_user/', views.create_user, name="create_user"),
    url(r'^profile_edit/', views.profile_edit, name="profile_edit"),
    url(r'^upload_photos/', views.photo_upload, name="photo_upload"),
    url(r'^recover/', views.recover_account, name="recover"),
    url(r'^login/', views.log_user_in, name="login"),
    url(r'^logout/', views.log_user_out, name="logout"),
    url(r'^register/', views.register, name="register"),
    url(r'^profile/(?P<sugarid>\d+)/$', views.profile, name="profile"),
    url(r'^payment/', views.payment, name="payment"),
    url(r'^home', views.home, name="home"),
    url(r'^paypal/', include('paypal.standard.ipn.urls')),
    url(r'^$', views.home, name="home"),
]
```

My profile view:

```
def profile(request, sugarid):
    if not request.user.is_authenticated():
        return redirect("home")

    variables = {}
    exists = SugarUser.objects.filter(user_id=sugarid)
    if exists:
        user = SugarUser.objects.get(user_id=sugarid)
        if not check_payment(user):
            return redirect("payment")

        midList = []
        lastList = []

        queryPhotos = UserPhoto.objects.filter(user_id=sugarid).order_by("-id")[:8]
        featuredPhoto = queryPhotos.values().first()
        midPhotos = queryPhotos[4:]
        for mid in midPhotos:
            midList.append(mid)
        if len(midList) < 4:
            result = 4 - len(midPhotos)
            for r in range(result):
                midList.append(None)

        lastPhotos = queryPhotos[1:4]
        for last in lastPhotos:
            lastList.append(last)
        if len(lastList) < 3:
            result = 3 - len(lastPhotos)
            for r in range(result):
                lastList.append(None)
        variables['name'] = user.name
        variables['status'] = user.status
        variables['description'] = user.description
        variables['whatyouwant'] = user.whatyouwant
        variables['state'] = user.state
        variables['city'] = user.city
        if featuredPhoto:
            variables['featuredPhoto'] = featuredPhoto['photo']
        else:
            variables['featuredPhoto'] = None
        variables['midPhotos'] = midList
        variables['lastPhotos'] = lastList
        variables['user'] = sugarid

    return render(request, "profile.html", variables)
```

My login user redirection view:

```
def log_user_in(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.POST['username']
        password = request.POST['password']
        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        if user is not None and user.is_active:
            login(request, user)
            return redirect("profile", kwargs={'sugarid': request.user.id})
```

I am getting this error ALWAYS:

```
django.core.urlresolvers.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'profile' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{'kwargs': {'sugarid': 24}}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['profile/(?P<sugarid>\\d+)/$']
```

I don't know what to do anymore, help :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should pass `sugarid` as a kwarg itself. This should work:

```
return redirect("profile", sugarid=request.user.id)
```

Comment: This worked, but now I'am getting NoReverseMatch error at all of my other URLS. This is annoying me for days :(

Every single URL he is trying the pattern "profile", I don't know why lol

Comment: can you elaborate a bit?

Comment: Nevermind, found my mistake, I was including "header.html" which was with a url 'profile' in all templates but not passing a argument when rendering. thanks for your time buddy. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can pass positional or keyword arguments as it is:

```
redirect("profile", sugarid=request.user.id)
```

Check the docs: 
[redirect in Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect)

Comment: This worked as @v1k45 said, but now I'am getting NoReverseMatch error at all of my other URLS.

Comment: Please give more details. Which urls fail and when do they fail, update your question or add a new one!

Comment: I have commented on @v1k45 answer my own mistake, thanks for the answer!